# Propensity vs. Probability

Tags: synonyms

What is the semantic difference between propensity and probability?

I'm thinking of a context like "Given his habbits, he has a high probability of dying of cancer".

Would the choice between propensity and probability be entirely taste-based here? Are there cases where they cannot be used synonymous.

Comment: I've put in an answer, but do note you can just glance in a dictionary for this one!

Comment: I have a probability for mischief...

Comment: Thanks. As mentioned in a comment to you answer. The reason that I did not trust the dictionary is that in some fields propensity is used seemingly in ways that are more closely related to probability. But I see that these are technical terms ([propensity probability](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Propensity_probability), [propensity score](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Propensity_score_matching))

Answer (score 5):

They're totally, utterly, different and totally unrelated.

A "propensity" is a quality of a person.

For example, I have a propensity to drink too much, I have a propensity to post on the ELU site, I have a propensity to get drunk (mentioned that one!), you have a propensity to watch sci-fi movies, etc etc.

"Probability" is a mathematical term and is just totally unrelated.

It has nothing at all to do with describing a person's propensities.

So, the probability of tossing heads is 50%, smokers have a 73% probability of cancer, I have a 88% probability of liver damage, etc etc.

"Propensity" is a quality of a person - simply, it relates to their choices in life.

(Your particular example perhaps leads to confusion, because, the sentence ***happens to include*** "a person" in the sentence.  But notice it is totally unrelated to their propensities - i.e., "things they like to do / usually choose". You're just stating a mathematical probability.  "Research shows that for his habits, he has a 82% probability of contracting cancer.")

Comment: I think what got me confused is stuff like [propensity probability](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Propensity_probability), [propensity score](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Propensity_score_matching), where propensity clearly used in a sense that is not related to people. But then again these are technical terms...